# Custom ordering products based on user role

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

My shop is currently set to sort products by ascending price.
Is there a way I can sort products by custom ordering for a specific user role only?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to this myself, for anyone wondering:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'change_catalog_orderby_specific_user');
function change_catalog_orderby_specific_user( $sort_by ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
        return 'menu_order';
    }
    else {
        return 'price';
    }
}
```